# jms adapter launch two jms consumer

Tags: spring-integration

I have a problem with int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter, when i start my application i see in activemq webadmin that i have two consumer for the queue.

```
<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter 
        id="jmsAdapter"
        acknowledge="transacted"
        destination-name="${destinationName}"
        connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory"
        channel="inboundChannel"
        auto-startup="true" >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="100" ></int:poller>
</int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Somme thing wrong in my conf?

Comment: Is this a web application? if so, the most common cause is you have the adapter declared in both the root and servlet contexts. If not, turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and examine the logs for bean declaration and consumer startup.

Comment: In addition: can you confirm that there is no any consumers, when you mark your adapter with ` auto-startup="false"`?

Comment: this is not a web application. When i put auto-startup = false, there is no consumer (it's normal).
In My application i have two parts : 
first : declarative message driven endpoint for specific queue
Second : Dynamic jms outbound adapter (With GenericApplicationContext like Dynamic ftp example in github)

When i comment The first part, i can see just one consumer. (????)
With log debug turned on in see that cachedConnectionFactory create a second consumer for queue but when i put a break point in cachedConnectionFactory just one consumer is created

Perhaps a multithreadind problem ?

Comment: In other word, I have a parentCtx that contains message driven endpoint. And childrenCtx that contains jms outbound adapter. childrenCtx ara created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
create multiple session, and one consumer per session . Sometimes i have 3 consumers for the same queue.

To resolve this i use cachedConsumer à false.